# Why in django admin foreign key displays attribute value but in angular and database it returns id?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

In Django admin, foreign key displays attribute value but in angular it returns id. DepartmentID is a foreign key which is displayed as dpt_name in dajngo admin but in database and anguar it is stored as id.
How to Display Foreign Key Value instead of ID in Angular 9?

```
        models.py

 Department table

    class Department(models.Model):
        DepartmentID = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key = True, verbose_name='Department ID')
        dpt_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='code', unique = True, blank = False, null = False)
        dpt_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='name', unique = True, blank = False, null = False)
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = '"tbl_department"'
            verbose_name_plural = "Department"
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.dpt_name

Program Table
  

      class Program(models.Model):
            
            programCode = models.CharField(max_length=3, primary_key = True, verbose_name='Program Code', unique = True)
            pro_name = models.CharField(default = 'B.Sc. Engg. in CSE', max_length=50, verbose_name='name', blank = False, null = False)
            pro_shortForm = models.CharField(default = 'CSE',max_length=20, verbose_name='short Form', blank = False, null = False)
            DepartmentID = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='department', db_column="DepartmentID")
        
        
            TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('honours', 'honours'),
        ('masters', 'masters'),
        ('diploma' , 'diploma'),
        ('PhD', 'PhD'),
        )
            
            pro_type = models.CharField(default = 'honours', max_length=7, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, verbose_name='type')
        
            class Meta:
                db_table = 'tbl_program'
                verbose_name_plural = "Program"
        
            def __str__(self):
                return self.pro_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Django admin displays the foreign key relations as the human readable form of the related object. Since you have implemented the `__str__` magic method, django admin would show the return value of that method.
Your angular code does nothing like this. The foreign key is just a column of that row, which is object id at the database.